# Netbeans handling of linux C++ signals

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb, beagleboneblack

I am building an application for Beaglebone Black using Netbeans running on a PC using remote compilation and debug. The debug has been straightforward up to this point, but I am now trying to sort out my serial comms. My serial code uses a signal to indicate data reception, and Netbeans halts my code to inform me of the signal. It offers 3 options: Discard and Continue, Discard and Pause, Forward and Continue. I want *none* of these! I want no notification of the signal at all, I want it to be handled by my code.

The options in Project Properties/Debug/Signals are to set them to Ignore (the program no longer responds to them) or Catch (pop up an annoying dialog that breaks my comms protocols). Is there is a way to get Netbeans to just carry on running as it ought to?

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using? It could be a bug!

Comment: Good question! I am running a development version of Netbeans because the last good release couldn't build on BeagleBone Black (due to the version of zip being wrong).